# HQL how to join three table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hql

I Have this classes:

```
 @Entity
 public class Category {
    private Long Id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private List<Product> products;
}

@Entity
public class Inventory {

    private Long id;
    private Product product;
    private int quantity;
}

@Entity
public class Product {
    private Long productId;
    private String name;
}
```

I want to get the Inventory given the id in the category. i'm trying to use this

```
return session.createQuery("select i from Inventory i, Category c join c.Products p outer join i.product = p WHERE c.Id=?")
                .setParameter(0, categoryId).list();
```

I'm really confused, please help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using criterias? They're much nicer for pulling data from the database.

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminDale I have found out the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright nevermind, I found out how to do it

```
Select i from Inventory i,Category c INNER JOIN i.product ip INNER JOIN c.products cp where ip = cp and c.id=?
```

So I was actually wondering how to relate the Category to the joins, I found the answer under Polymorphic queries in HQL documentation