# problems in a HQL query with nested objects

Tags: hibernate, jpa

i have these two class and a code to insert data:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "quiz_test")
public class QuizTest implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "quiz_id")
    private Quiz quiz;


@Entity(name = "Quiz")
@Table(name = "quiz")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id")
public class Quiz implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<StudentClass> stClasses= new ArrayList<>();
```

I would like to make a query to search all the quizzes of a StudentClass like this:

```
public List<StatStudentClass> getStatistic(StudentClass sc){
    List<QuizTest> resultDb=(List<QuizTest>) hibernateTemplate.find("FROM QuizTest qt WHERE qt.quiz.stClasses= ?", sc);
}
```

but I have this error:

> org.hibernate.QueryException: Expected positional parameter count: 1, actual parameters: [StudentClass [id=2, name=Seconde A, startDate=2018-06-27, endDate=2018-11-05, students=[fr.dawan.autoquiz3000.beans.User@c1f72974, fr.dawan.autoquiz3000.beans.User@b15245c3, fr.dawan.autoquiz3000.beans.User@7f943dc1, fr.dawan.autoquiz3000.beans.User@9eaa7d67, fr.dawan.autoquiz3000.beans.User@e7d21a2c, fr.dawan.autoquiz3000.beans.User@cfbe7565], version=7]] [FROM QuizTest qt INNER JOIN qt.quiz q WHERE q.stClasses= ?]

Someone could explain to me what I'm doing wrong!

thank you!

Comment: QuizTest.java is not mapped with StudentClass.java but with Quiz.java, and the return of the method is empty.   you can try polymorphic queries  ("FROM QuizTest qt, Quiz q INNER JOIN qt.quiz qtq INNER JOIN q.stClasses qs WHERE qtq=qs and  q.stClasses= ?", sc) for more detail see this [respense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20570351/hql-how-to-join-three-table)

Comment: stClasses is a List<StudentClass>. How could a List<StudentClass> be equal to a StudentClass? You need an additional join. Here's the documentation about them: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join. The PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation also doesn't make any sense, and you probably want a ManyToOne, not a OneToOne, since a quiz can probably be tested more than once.